# Query deleted records using talend

Tags: talend

I want to query deleted records in `Salesforce` and retrieve the `LastModifiedDate` of these records.

My query:

```
"Select LastModifiedDate FROM Custom_Table__c WHERE  customFields = '456_0_1' ALL ROWS"
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
java.io.IOException: [MalformedQueryFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='MALFORMED_QUERY'
 exceptionMessage='
 customFields = '456_0_1' ALL ROWS
                         ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:111
unexpected token: 'ALL ROWS'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try escaping '456_0_1' as \'456_0_1\'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because ALL ROWS is only allowed with SOQL inside of APEX code, so this is not going to work.

But since you are using talend, this is done easily by executing the following query and checking the "Include deleted records" checkbox as shown below:

[image]

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I have to use the component's feature.